# Scala: Is there a way to mark created-at timestamp column read-only in slick

Tags: scala, slick

Is there a way we can achieve this in Slick ? When a record is created, the timestamp is set but cannot be changed after that..

Comment: What type of database are you using?  This should probably business-layer logic and not data storage logic.

Comment: Using MySQL but want to be database agnostic. Wonder if there is a way to do that while defining the column as in     def createdAt = column[Option[DateTime]]("CREATED_AT")

Comment: Well... the column does not reside with `slick` but with the database. So the answer is no. Slick will not be able to help with that unless your database has someway of doing that.

Comment: This is a great question and needs to be solved. Somehow the case class needs to be able to READ the database values but never WRITE them. Fields like CreateStamp, ModStamp and Revision need to be completely under the database's dominion and yet are so handy to have in the case class for any number of reasons. However the moment you put them into the case class slick wants to write those values out to the DB. We need "lopsided" reads versus write here or a way to ensure that data in those fields is never written back to the DB. You would think it would be a simple flag on the column def